# How do I use jquery to manipulate a Div I've already pointed to?

Tags: jquery, dom, yui

I know in jQuery you can point to an element by $('#idname') but I'm using an API that returns to me the entire div element, as if it used document.getElementById().

I know a quick hack could be:

```
var a = getContainerEl.id;
$('#' + a);
```

but is there a more elegant way? I need access to this to add to it's DOM.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's easy: `$(getContainerEl)`

Answer (score 4):

jQuery takes a DOM object just as easily as a CSS selector.

```
jQuery(getContainerEl)
```